# Docx4j export to PDF/A-1b - base14 fonts embedding

Tags: pdf, apache-fop, docx4j

I need to export a docx document to PDF/A-1b on a Ubuntu server, using the Apache FOP backend.

The document is nothing fancy, it uses the basic windows fonts Calibri, Courier New, Times New Roman, Symbol, Wingdings.
The PDF/A-1b profile requires embedding of all fonts, including the standard base-14 ones, so I have extracted the Ubuntu Type1 fonts from /usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35 and I have 14 .pfb and 14 .afm files in the `/home/luca/Desktop/ubuntufonts/` path.

I think I set up everything correctly, but enabling the A-1b profile causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Neither an AFM nor a PFM file was found for NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.pfb
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.type1.Type1FontLoader.read(Type1FontLoader.java:147)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontLoader.getFont(FontLoader.java:126)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontLoader.loadFont(FontLoader.java:110)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.load(LazyFont.java:119)
...
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read font file NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.pfb
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.load(LazyFont.java:132)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.hasChar(LazyFont.java:179)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.Font.hasChar(Font.java:278)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontSelector.selectFontForCharacter(FontSelector.java:47)
    at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontSelector.selectFontForCharacterInText(FontSelector.java:85)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.TextLayoutManager.initialize(TextLayoutManager.java:162)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.getChildLM(AbstractLayoutManager.java:118)
```

But the files are right there:

```
luca@luca-vm:~/Desktop/ubuntufonts$ ls
D050000L.afm                 NimbusRoman-Italic.afm
D050000L.pfb                 NimbusRoman-Italic.pfb
NimbusMonoPS-Bold.afm        NimbusRoman-Regular.afm
NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.afm  NimbusRoman-Regular.pfb
NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.pfb  NimbusSans-Bold.afm
NimbusMonoPS-Bold.pfb        NimbusSans-BoldItalic.afm
NimbusMonoPS-Italic.afm      NimbusSans-BoldItalic.pfb
NimbusMonoPS-Italic.pfb      NimbusSans-Bold.pfb
NimbusMonoPS-Regular.afm     NimbusSans-Italic.afm
NimbusMonoPS-Regular.pfb     NimbusSans-Italic.pfb
NimbusRoman-Bold.afm         NimbusSans-Regular.afm
NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.afm   NimbusSans-Regular.pfb
NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.pfb   StandardSymbolsPS.afm
NimbusRoman-Bold.pfb         StandardSymbolsPS.pfb
```

From a web search, it seems that the way to proceed is to create a fop.xml configuration file, mapping the font names to the files I extracted. This is the file I prepared:

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <font-base>/home/luca/Desktop/ubuntufonts/</font-base>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Regular.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Bold.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Italic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-BoldItalic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                </font>

                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Regular.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Bold.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Italic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>

                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Regular.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Bold.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Italic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                </font>

                <font embed-url="StandardSymbolsPS.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>

                <font embed-url="D050000L.pfb" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="ZapfDingbats" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="ZapfDingbats" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

This is the final conversion code I'm using:

```
        // Document loading (required)
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(classPathResource.getFile());

        // Set up font mapper (optional)
        Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
        wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);

        // FO exporter setup (required)
        // .. the FOSettings object
        String fopConfig = Files.readString(new ClassPathResource("fop.xml").getFile().toPath());
        FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
        foSettings.setApacheFopConfiguration(fopConfig);
        foSettings.setOpcPackage(wordMLPackage);

        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = FORendererApacheFOP.getFOUserAgent(foSettings);
        foUserAgent.getRendererOptions().put("pdf-a-mode", "PDF/A-1b");

        // PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2a and PDF/A-3a require accessibility to be enabled
        // see further https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587413/1031689
        foUserAgent.setAccessibility(true); // suppress "missing language information" messages from FOUserAgent .processEvent

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);

        // Clean up, so any ObfuscatedFontPart temp files can be deleted 
        if (wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart()!=null) {
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart().deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles();
        }       
        // This would also do it, via finalize() methods
        foSettings = null;
        wordMLPackage = null;
```

I also tried embedding the document fonts directly in the Word document and deleting fop caches between the various attempts, but these actions did not resolve the issue.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, after wasting more than two days on it. For some reason the  element must be prefixed with a scheme:

```
<font-base>file:/home/luca/Desktop/ubuntufonts/</font-base>
```

Now, I also want to point out for the future frustrated reader that there is actually no reason to use a Type1 font to map the Base14 fonts, so do yourself a favour and map them using OTF fonts (on my Ubuntu vm they're at `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35`), so there is no need for extra AFM/PFM file lookups.

This is my final xml config file:

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <font-base>file:/home/luca/Desktop/ubuntuttf/</font-base>
    <use-cache>false</use-cache>
    <strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Regular.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                    <font-triplet name="SansSerif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Bold.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                    <font-triplet name="SansSerif" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-Italic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                    <font-triplet name="SansSerif" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusSans-BoldItalic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Calibri" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                    <font-triplet name="SansSerif" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
    
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Regular.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                    <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Bold.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="serif" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                    <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-Italic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="serif" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                    <font-triplet name="any" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="serif" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                    <font-triplet name="any" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
    
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Regular.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="monospace" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Italic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="monospace" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-Bold.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="italic" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="monospace" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>
                <font embed-url="NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="Courier New" style="italic" weight="bold" />
                    <font-triplet name="monospace" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                </font>
    
                <font embed-url="StandardSymbolsPS.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="Symbol" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>
    
                <font embed-url="D050000L.otf">
                    <font-triplet name="ZapfDingbats" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                    <font-triplet name="ZapfDingbats" style="normal" weight="bold" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Also, if anyone is interested into embedding fonts into a jar/war archive, just change the font-base element into `<font-base>classpath:/fonts/</font-base>` and add your font files under `/src/main/resources/fonts/`.